# && Equivalent in Powershell

Tags: scripting, command-line, powershell

In bash I use `./task1.sh && ./task2.sh` to run task1, and then run task2 as long as task1 did not return an error code. When I try `.\task1.bat && .\task2.bat` in Powershell I get the error "The Token && Is not a valid separator in this version."

Is there an equivalent for && in Windows Powershell?

Comment: it's only proper ettiquette to select an answer when your question has been answered on the Stack Exchange network. please select an answer. thanks!

Comment: Whoever is interested in Bash-style `&&` and `||` becoming a part of PowerShell: please vote for the feature [here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11087898-implement-the-and-operators-that-bash-has).

Comment: You can just do `(command) -and (command)`

Answer (score 18):

This is the closest I can get:

```
  .\task1.ps1 ; if($?){.\task2.ps1}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the closest equivalent would be:

```
.\task1.bat;if($lastexitcode -eq 0){.\task2.bat}
```

Also, Powershell has `-and` which you might want to try, but it is not really the same.